# Writing a userscript that replaces a background image

Tags: javascript, background, greasemonkey, userscripts

This is the code

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Wood Background
// @namespace      http://www.nationstates.net/nation=ellorn
// @description    Changes background to wood finish
// @include       http:*//w11.zetaboards.com/Allied_Republics/*
// ==/UserScript==


function addCss(cssString) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    return unless head;
    var newCss = document.createElement('style');
    newCss.type = "text/css";
    newCss.innerHTML = cssString;
    head.appendChild(newCss);
}  
addCss (
    '* { background: #00ff00                          url('http://awesomewallpapers.files.wordpress.com/2010/01 /wooden_top.jpg') no-repeat 

fixed center;  }'
);
```

I'm trying to replace the background of the site: http://awesomewallpapers.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/wooden_top.jpg

Comment: You know your quotation is broken and you can't use line breaks like that without escaping 'em right?

Comment: Try `addCss ("* { background: #00ff00                          url('http://awesomewallpapers.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/wooden_top.jpg') no-repeat fixed center;  }"` I'd suggest replacing the `*` by `body` or another selector, `*` will have an unpredictable effect.

Answer (score 2):

For just style changes, use [the Stylish add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) (some variant of this is available on almost every browser).

Stylish is faster, lighter, and easier than Greasemonkey or userscripts.  There are plenty of pre-made styles available at [userstyles.org](http://userstyles.org/).

Barring that, use built-in functions, like [`GM_addStyle()`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_addStyle).

The following script works on Firefox and Chrome, and probably a few other browsers. (There was a syntax error in the CSS string) :

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Wood Background
// @namespace   http://www.nationstates.net/nation=ellorn
// @description Changes background to wood finish
// @include     http:*//w11.zetaboards.com/Allied_Republics/*
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle (
    "* { background: #00ff00 "
    + "url('http://awesomewallpapers.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/wooden_top.jpg')"
    + " no-repeat fixed center; }"
);
```

Note that it would be best to replace the `*` with `body`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own user-stylesheet to overwrite the author stylesheets of websites. I think this would be better suited to alter CSS than writing javascript.

Here is [a short introduction](http://brugbart.com/Articles/custom-style-sheets) on how to achieve that.

Besides from that your code should work in general if you hand over the CSS-string correctly (fixed quoting and linebreak):

```
var css = "* { background: #00ff00 url('http://awesomewallpapers.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/wooden_top.jpg') no-repeat fixed center;  }";

addCss ( css );
```

Note however, that `*` will break, since you are applying the wooden background to **every** element, not only your background-element (HTML or body or a wrapper div).